# Отображение графиков в HTML письме

Tags: javascript, html, email, canvas, svg

Есть рассылка по пользователям раз в неделю с информацией. Только эта информация более наглядно будет смотреться в виде графика.
Вопрос: как отображать графики в HTML письме?

Iframe, JavaScript отпадает через неподражаемость в почтовых клиентах.

Есть мысль рендерить картинку, рабочий пример с сайта https://woody.aviasales.ru/graph.png?last_prices=14328,18610&average_price=14950

Они рендерят картинку по GET параметрах.

Как это сделать?

Есть проще альтернативы?

Comment: Картинку можно и на серверной стороне сваять, и отдать с нужным доктайпом так что никто ничего не заподозрит) как будто это статичный файл. Я делал когда то png графики на php, но это было 100 лет назад, кроме слова imagemagic уже не помню ничего

Comment: @Darth
Подскажете пожалуйста как это сделать с помощу PHP -  например в файле char.php z что то вывел. Как мне содержание char.php вывести через тег img в файле index.html?

Answer (score 3):

Такие графики обычно рисуются на php с помощью библиотеки GD http://php.net/manual/ru/book.image.php . Мы обращаемся по указанному адресу к скрипту, однако он на выходе отдает не html-документ, а изображение, сгенерированое на лету исходя из get-параметров.

Стандартный скрипт выглядит примерно так:

```
header("Content-type: image/png"); //сообщаем браузеру, что посылается картинка
$string = $_GET['text'];
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("images/button1.png");//создаем картинку
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 210, 60); //что-то рисуем
$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($string)) / 2;
imagestring($im, 3, $px, 9, $string, $orange);
imagepng($im);//выводим изображение в буфер вывода
imagedestroy($im);//особождаем память
```

Там есть самые простые методы - рисование линии, дуги, эллипсы, заливки и т.д. Вообщем пайнт.

Однако есть библиотеки, надстройки на GD, например, [pchart](http://www.pchart.net/features) или [jpgraph](http://jpgraph.net/) упрощающие работу с графиками, возможно вам следует их попробовать для вашей задачи.